# How to check if a rectangle at a given position exists

Tags: java, graphics, rectangles

im trying to draw rectangles of different sizes on a grid for a uni assignment. so what i want to do is drawing and colouring them in blue. but i want to check first if at a given position a rectangle  exists. is there a method in the library for this or do i have to develop that method. In the latter case where should i start?

thanks!

Comment: *is there a method in the library*... Which library?

Comment: Look at the intersection methods  of java.awt.Rectangle

Comment: You can check with the color. If the color is blue, there exists a rectangle..

Comment: Hey Ramesh , good advice. is there a way to check the colour of a certain area on the jpanel ?  for the "Graphics2d" there is a getcolor() method.  but if i want to get the colour of just a certain part with the given position and  size : (x, y, width, height), how do i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have an LTRB (`left/top/right/bottom`) representation for a rectangle. You can check if a point (`x,y`) is inside the rectangle like so:

```
boolean pointInRect(int x, int y, int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
     return x >= l && x <= r && 
            y >= t && y <= b;
}
```

Note that if you use `java.awt.Rectangle`, there is a `contains` method that already does this, though I'm not sure if that would be considered "cheating" or not in the context of a school assignment.

So given a position, you can iterate through a list of rectangles you have (the same ones you draw to the screen) and see which one contains the point/position.

If you want to do this in faster than linear time, you can use, say, a quad-tree or partition your rectangles into a fixed NxM grid. In the latter case, you can just check the rectangles that belong to the same grid cell the mouse cursor is over. That might be overkill for this assignment though.

**Edit**

After some back-and-forth, I think more helpful to your situation is a test to see if a rectangle overlaps with another.

```
// Returns true if two solid rectangles intersect.
bool rectIntersect(int l1, int t1, int r1, int b1,
                   int l2, int t2, int r2, int b2)
{
     return l1 <= r2 && r1 >= l2 &&
            t1 <= b2 && b1 >= t2;
}
```

Using this function, whenever you want to add a new rectangle, you can loop through the existing rectangles you have and see if any one of them intersect the new one you're trying to add. This isn't the most efficient approach, but it should give you the desired behavior.

Comment: Hey Ike, thx for the answer. i want no mouse-cursor involved,   the rectangles won't have a mouselistener. i just want to make sure the (x,y) spot where the next rectangle is gonna be placed on the Grid is empty.. and i can use the contains method if i know it solves my problem.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll remove the reference to mouse cursor. The above method should hold for any kind of arbitrary position though to check if a rectangle already exists there.

Comment: Now if you have already have grid cells, does a rectangle occupy the full cell of a grid? If so, you can just use this method with the center of a cell. More efficient though is associate the rectangle with the grid cell (store it in the cell). Then you can just check to see if the cell is empty by checking its data to determine whether a rectangle occupies it or not.

Comment: the rectangles come in different sizes. they only occupy full cells, at least one full cell, or two or  three etc... what you have described in your  comment though is lil more than what i can do with java. too many questions: like how to communicate with a grid cell (the grid consisting basically of  (a,b) number of horizontal and vertical lines), get the centre of a cell, how to assign multiple cells to a rectangle etc.?

Comment: I see -- in that case, maybe what you want is a test to see if a rectangle overlaps with an existing one. Then you can add a new rectangle if it doesn't overlap with any existing ones. Lemme edit the answer.

Comment: imho, maybe just checking whether the given (x,y) coordinate where the upperleft corner of the rectangle should ideally be, is in another rectangle could be easier than first creating a rectangle and then checking whether it is overlapping and if yes deleting it?? please correct me if my logic is wrong

Comment: If the rectangles can be arbitrarily-sized to occupy any number of grid cells, that might not hold up if you are trying to add a short rectangle below a tall one, e.g. (where the short one's upper-left corner is below the tall one's upper-left corner). The overlapping check gives you a more general way to test, "Does this rectangular area already have a rectangle within it?"

Comment: thanks a lot. hope i will manage to solve, might come back to you if i cant :-)